# Issue with 12-megapixel High Quality Camera

Tags: camera

I have a strange issue with my camera. I have installed it correctly, if I enter:

```
libcamera-still -o test.jpg
[0:47:15.362288136] [3186]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
[0:47:15.417510467] [3187]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:437 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx296@1a to Unicam device /dev/media1 and ISP device /dev/media2
[0:47:15.417688132] [3187]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1101 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[0:47:15.422014078] [3186]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 728x544-YUV420
[0:47:15.422787605] [3187]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx296@1a - Selected sensor format: 1456x1088-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1456x1088-pBAA
[0:47:21.040437623] [3186]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 1456x1088-YUV420 (1) 1456x1088-SBGGR10_CSI2P
[0:47:21.041348501] [3187]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx296@1a - Selected sensor format: 1456x1088-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1456x1088-pBAA
Still capture image received
```

I'm getting a blur preview, but I can see something.
[image]

The camera has been switch on on the raspi config menu.

**BUT**, I can't see it in the Raspberry Pi Configuration window (with interfaces, above SSH). BTW, all interfaces are ON.

If I enter:

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

I get:

```
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

```
raspistill -o image.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not enabled in this build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled
```

I run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Please, help me Obi-Wan, you are my only hope :D

Comment: It looks like a focus/autofocus problem more than anything else. Have you read the Raspberry Pi docs on the Raspberry Pi website at: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html

Comment: why is the issue "strange"?

Comment: @jsotola strange, because the camera is not shown in the Configuration menu:
!https://ibb.co/gFjnhxf (I don't know how to paste a picture)

Comment: now I'm really confused. If I run today  

`libcamera-still -o test.jpg`  
I get:
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:01:06.241061016] [2032]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***


and if I run
`vcgencmd get_camera` I'm getting:
supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0

May it be, that the camera is broken?

Comment: command ´raspistill -o image.jpg`  

is returning with:
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

Comment: I got the cam to work. Somehow a software update removed in the config.txt file the line "camera _auto_detect=1". 

Now, if I run `vcgencmd get_camera` I get "supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0" and the camera is still not visible under Interfaces, but at least it is working